# the image does not show in canvas Everytime I refresh the page `with` cleaning the browser cache

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a JavaScript as follow:

```
function analyze_getData(url){
    $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: url, 
        secureuri: false, 
        fileElementId: ['upload-file'], 
        dataType: "JSON", 
        data:{ "sample_path":src },
        success: function (data)  
        {
            data=JSON.parse(data);
            var json = JSON.stringify(data.prediction, undefined, 4)
            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
            ctx.lineWidth=10;
            for(var i=1; i<data.prediction.length; ++i){
              var score_location=data.prediction[i][i.toString()]
              var l=score_location['location']
              ctx.strokeRect(l['left'], l['top'], l['width'], l['height'])
            }
        },
        error: function (data)
        {
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var img_buffer = document.createElement('img');
    src=$(".demo-view-container-left .view img").attr("src")
    img_buffer.src=src
    var imgWidth=img_buffer.width;
    var imgHeight=img_buffer.height;

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    c.width = imgWidth;
    c.height = imgHeight;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    analyze_getData("xxx/demo")
})
```

Everytime I refresh the page `with` cleaning the browser cache, the image does not show  in canvas. But then after I again refresh the page `without` cleaning the cache, the image can normally show in the canvas.

Why is that?
can anyone give some advises?
thank you very much~

Comment: Just follow the code in the dup. answer and implement a onload handler for your img object in the latter part of the code.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand your meaning.   You marked my problem as duplicate, but I can not find the duplicate one like mine. Can you provide the link of it or other referable links solving my problem? thank you.

Comment: See the last five lines in the code above; you need to implement a onload handler *as* in the dup answer.